# Don't manage to figure out why class-div won't get color from CSS

Tags: html, css

Probably something simple which I don't understand. The structure is taken from mozilla's homepage.

The textboxes won't get the color "red" set in the CSS when it is added for the class .siteText.

My CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.siteText{
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
          <div class=siteText" id="textbox1">One</div>
          <div class=siteText" id="textbox2">Two</div>
          <div class=siteText" id="textbox3">per libero et d</div>
          <div class=siteImage" id="imagebox3">Six</div>
    </div>
```

Putting in #textbox1 instead of .siteText works so is there something that is inherited in some way I don't understand or is there something wrong with the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the opening quotes in every instance of `class=siteText"`. that should be `class="siteText"` (and also `class="siteImage"`)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}

.siteText{
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
          <div class="siteText" id="textbox1">One</div>
          <div class="siteText" id="textbox2">Two</div>
          <div class="siteText" id="textbox3">per libero et d</div>
          <div class="siteImage" id="imagebox3">Six</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm blind... :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using only color instead of background-color.

```
.siteText{
  color:red;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Missing the First " in The Class